# Generate Report Cover in another Report Application (.rdlc)

Tags: c#, reporting, rdlc

Good people, I need to make a cover (***rdlc***) separate from the detail of the report.
I thought about making 2 reports of application by means of Constructors, to pass to the report the title page (***ReportViewer***) to render it, but then to put them together I am not finding another way but to unite the pdf files by means of ***ITextSharp*** (.dll).

Do you have any other think of how I can link the Cover page on the first page and the detail of the Report on the following pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separately create report cover and put it as a subreport in the main report.

In order to display cover and main report on different pages you can use a Rectangle with minimum height and `PageBreak = Start` (red rectangle in the picture below).

[image: report with cover]

Comment: I've the following question ... Can I call (LoadSubreportDefinition) by means of a Stream to report that comes from another ReportsApplication ??

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it, the inconvenience I was having was that the report (.rdlc) is not inside the execution folder of report Applications, for that I replicated a copy of the report file to the project from where I am calling it as a subreport.